# How to set size, position, and color, of one RadialGradient, or set XferMode on GradientDrawable

Tags: java, android, shader

This is my first question here on Stackoverflow, so go easy on me. I'm trying to draw a radial bloom effect around a point, and found RadialGradient, as well as GradientDrawable. However neither fully gives a solution.

Here is how I'm doing the drawing right now:

```
//global
PorterDuffXfermode xferMode = new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.ADD);
Paint mainP = new Paint();
Paint whiteP = new Paint();
whiteP.setColor(Color.WHITE);
RadialGradient gradient;

// in a drawing method with a canvas
gradient = new RadialGradient((int) x, (int) y, tempRadius, mainP.getColor(),
    0x00000000, Shader.TileMode.CL
mainP.setShader(gradient);
mainP.setXfermode(xferMode);

canvas.drawCircle((int) x, (int) y, tempRadius, mainP);

gradient = new RadialGradient((int) x, (int) y, tempRadius/2, whiteP.getColor(),
      0x00000000, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
whiteP.setXfermode(xferMode);
whiteP.setShader(gradient);

canvas.drawCircle((int) x, (int) y, tempRadius/2, whiteP);
```

This will give the expected result:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAjhP.png)

However the new RadialGradient builds up in memory every frame per dot. Which becomes a problem later obviously. The only public thing in that class is a constructor, so all you can do with RadialGradient is create a new one every time you need a new size, position or color. The reason I want to do it this way is because you assign the gradient to the Paint object your going to draw it with, which allows you to use it's setXferMode().

The other way, using the GradientDrawable, does allow you to just create one instance of itself, so you can change the size, position, and color, but the Paint object it uses to paint itself is private, so you can't set the XferMode on it. Which is necessary so that if you have more than one dot, they don't just paint over one another. It has a colorfilter, but it doesn't look like colorfilter worries about the destination, only a specified color and the source.

Since I am new, i can only post two links, and instead of posting just two pictures, I'll link back to the same question I wrote on reddit which has all the pictures for context. (and no answers yet, which is why I came here, ha ha)

https://www.reddit.com/r/learnandroid/comments/590uce/having_a_shader_issue_using_radialgradient_and/

So, how should this be done, I know I need one class or the other. From what I can tell, RadialGradient would be perfect if I didn't have to create a new one every time I needed a different size, position, or color. GradientDrawable would be equally great since you can just have one instance, but I need to be able to set the XferMode on the paint it uses. Is there another class, or am I missing something between the two of these?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

So, while I did find a solution, it still lead to more issues. The solution I found was partly [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14872177/how-to-preallocate-radialgradient). The only thing it was missing was being able to change the color of the preallocated RadialGradient bitmap. So I came up with this:

```
// Global
int tempRadius;
Paint p = new Paint();
RadialGradient gradient;    
Bitmap circleBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) (tempRadius * 2.0f), (int) (tempRadius * 2.0f),
Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas tempCanvas = new Canvas(circleBitmap);
Rect gradBMPRect = new Rect(0,0,200,200);
Rect destRect = new Rect();
int[] hsv = {0,1,1};
PorterDuffColorFilter[] myColors = new PorterDuffColorFilter[360];
PorterDuffXfermode xferMode = new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.ADD);


// Initialize
gradient = new RadialGradient(tempRadius, tempRadius, tempRadius, Color.WHITE, 0x00000000, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
circleBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) (100 * 2.0f), (int) (100 * 2.0f),
Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
tempCanvas = new Canvas(circleBitmap);
for(int i = 0; i < 360; i++){
  hsv[0] = i;
  myColors[i] = new PorterDuffColorFilter(Color.HSVtoColor(hsv), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY)
}

// update/draw
p.setDither(true);
p.setShader(gradient);
tempCanvas.drawCircle(100, 100, 100, p);
p.setXfermode(xferMode);


if(p.getColor() != mainP.getColor()) {
p.setColorFilter(myColors[hue]);
p.setColor(mainP.getColor());

destRect.set((int)x-tempRadius,(int)y-tempRadius,(int)x+tempRadius,(int)y+tempRadius);
canvas.drawBitmap(circleBitmap,gradBMPRect,destRect,p);

p.setColorFilter(null);
destRect.set((int)x-(tempRadius/2),(int)y-(tempRadius/2),(int)x+(tempRadius/2),(int)y+(tempRadius/2));
canvas.drawBitmap(circleBitmap,gradBMPRect,destRect,p);
```

With this the RadialGradient is used to create a greyscaled bitmap, then a pallette of 360 PorterDuffColorFilters is made using HSVtoColor. All 360 have their modes set to multiply. When drawing these the paint used to draw the bitmap is set use the ColorFilter specified by its hue. The colorfilter shades the greyscaled bitmap to whatever color the filter is. And no more memory leaks :)

This took longer to render the bitmap of a RadialGradient vs rendering a circle with a RadialGradient though. With 30 circles it took my Galaxy S5 15-20ms per frame draw, while the bitmaps took around 30-35ms. It could probably get worked out though with a little more work and adjustment.